# AutoCompleteBox or ComboBox with search? (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am writing a Windows Store app which will enale the user to search for a job choosing a postion and region from given sets. The obvious choice is to have a `Combobox` for positions and another combobox for region, but the standard combobox is a realy bad componet. It expandes ind a strange way but I guess this can be changed by styling. The problem is when there are a lot of items in a combobox (regions, position in my case) the UX is very bad, searching by typing is needed.

Is there an `AutoCompleteBox` component (I have not found any) or an easy way to make the `ComboBox` search its items while typing? I guess I am not the only one who needs such functionality.

**EDIT**
I tried the `Combobox`'s `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` methods to catch the key pressed and setting the `SelectedItem` to an item I want and the to null, this brings the item into view and does not make it selected. The problem is that after I set the `SelectedItem` after the first key is pressed, neither `KeyUp` no `KeyDown` are called again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written my own AutoCompleteBox, available at https://github.com/igorkulman/AutoCompleteBox

Comment: how to disable xaml ab:AutoCompleteBox suggestions list in autocompletebox ?(In Basic touch mode)